# Tetrahedron inequality

Tags: geometry

Do we have an analogue to triangle inequality in 3-D say tetrahedron inequality(or any other relation), which once satisfied by any  six real numbers; implies an existence of a tetrahedron with those side lengths?

Comment: added geometry tag. I don't think algebraic geometers studied this sort of thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On any non-degenerate tetrahedron, pick any vertex and let $a, b, c$ be the length of edges connected to it. Let $\tilde{a},\tilde{b},\tilde{c}$ be the length of corresponding opposite edges. 
The edges on all six faces will satisfy triangular inequalities. These inequalities can
be summarized in a single statement:
$$\min(a+b+c,a+\tilde{b}+\tilde{c},\tilde{a}+b+\tilde{c},\tilde{a}+\tilde{b}+c) 
> \max(a+\tilde{a},b+\tilde{b},c+\tilde{c})\tag{*1}$$
Furthermore, the corresponding [Calyer-Menger determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html) is positive. Up to a scaling factor,
it means:
$$\left|\begin{matrix}0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\cr 1 & 0 & {a}^{2} & {b}^{2} & {c}^{2}\cr 1 & {a}^{2} & 0 & \tilde{c}^{2} & \tilde{b}^{2}\cr 1 & {b}^{2} & \tilde{c}^{2} & 0 & \tilde{a}^{2}\cr 1 & {c}^{2} & \tilde{b}^{2} & \tilde{a}^{2} & 0\end{matrix}\right| > 0\tag{*2}$$

Given any 6 positive numbers, if $(*1)$ and $(*2)$ are satisfied, then it can be realized as the edge lengths of a non-degenerate tetrahedron.

For a proof of this, please see the paper 
[Edge lengths determining tetrahedrons](http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_pdf.php?issn=0013-6018&vol=64&iss=4&rank=4) 
by Karl Wirth and Andre S. Dreiding.

**Side Notes**

About the inequalities of face areas mentioned in Glen O's answer. It is also a sufficient condition. More precisely, give any 4 positive numbers $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$. If can be realized as the face areas of a non-degenerate tetrahedron if and only if the following 4
inequalities are satisfied:

$$\begin{cases} A_2 + A_3 + A_4 > A_1\\A_3 + A_4 + A_1 > A_2\\ A_4 + A_1 + A_2 > A_3\\ A_1 + A_2 + A_3 > A_4\end{cases}$$

For a proof of this, please see answers in a related question ([Inequality for each $a, b, c, d$ being each area of four faces of a tetrahedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/477964/59379)).

Comment: The paper refers to address the issue comprehensively

Answer (score 2):

There won't be a single inequality between the six edges (there'll be a set of four inequalities, one for each side), but there should be an inequality between the four faces.

That is,

$$
A_1 + A_2 + A_3 \geq A_4
$$
Where 1, 2, 3, and 4 are the four faces.

This would resolve as a set of cross products - if you have the origin as one point, and the other three points as $A$, $B$, and $C$, then you have

$$
|A\times B| + |A\times C| + |B\times C| \geq |(A-C)\times(B-C)|
 = \left|(A\times B) - (A\times C) - (B\times C)\right|$$

Answer (score 1):

On any non-degenerate tetrahedron, let a,b,c be the lengths of edges which form a triangle. Let d,e,f be the lengths of corresponding opposite edges. The edges on all four faces will satisfy triangular inequalities. These inequalities can be summarized in a single Boolean expression:

$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
(a+b>c) & \operatorname{and} &(a+c>b) &\operatorname{and} &(b+c>a)& \operatorname{and} \\
(c+d>e) &\operatorname{and} &(c+e>d) &\operatorname{and} &(d+e>c)& \operatorname{and} & & (1)\\
(b+d>f) &\operatorname{and} &(b+f>d) &\operatorname{and} &(d+f>b) &\operatorname{and}\\
(a+e>f) &\operatorname{and} &(a+f>e) &\operatorname{and} &(e+f>a)
\end{array}$$

Furthermore, the corresponding McCrea determinant is positive:

$$  \begin{vmatrix}
    2d^2   &   d^2+e^2-c^2 & f^2+d^2-b^2  \\
    d^2+e^2-c^2  &   2e^2  &    e^2+f^2-a^2  \\
    f^2+d^2-b^2 & e^2+f^2-a^2   &  2f^2     \end{vmatrix}>  0 \qquad (2)$$

Given any 6 positive numbers, if $(1)$ and $(2)$ are satisfied, then it can be realized as the edge lengths of a non-degenerate tetrahedron.

Please see the paper by Mussa:
https://academiccommons.columbia.edu/doi/10.7916/D8J96DP9/download