# How can triangle inequlity be extended to become tetrahedron inequlity?

Tags: inequality

Since each side of a tetrahedron is a triangle is it possible to have an inequality that involves triangles that can form a tetrahedron?

Comment: See answer to this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/513071/59379), it cover two cases where 1. only the lengths of 6 edges are given and 2. only the areas of 4 faces are given.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking "Find the necessary and sufficient condition that each of four positive numbers $a,b,c,d$ represents each area of the face of a tetrahedron", then it is known that the answer is $$a\lt b+c+d,b\lt a+c+d, c\lt a+b+d, d\lt a+b+c.$$

Answer (score 0):

But if you are asking "Find the necessary and sufficient condition
that each of *six* positive numbers represents each 
*edge* of a tetrahedron", then it is known that the answer is
the following:

1. all triangle inequalities for the faces must be fulfilled
2. the [Cayley-Menger Determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html) must be positive