# Generalization of triangle inequality in tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, triangle-inequality

Let $(a,b)$, $(c,d)$, $(e,f)$ be oppisite edges of the tetrahedron. Our teacher said there's a generalization of triangle inequality: $$ab+cd>ef$$
but I don't know how prove it, and I'm not sure whether it's true because I didn't see any similar results on the Internet. Could someone give me some advise? Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with Ptolemy's theorem? If so, apply that same proof (esp the triangle inequality approach), just that the points are in 3-D space instead of 2-D space. We have strict inequality because a 3-D tetrahedron cannot be concyclic (in a 2-D plane).

Comment: @CalvinLin I got it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513071/tetrahedron-inequality and the questions linked there.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, turned out this specific thing is  called  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_inequality  as opposed to Ptolemy's Theorem, which I hadn't known either.