# What is lower limit condition of a surface of a tetrahedron?

Tags: geometry, 3d

$S_1$, $S_2$, $S_3$, and $S_4$ are the areas of the four faces.

We know that a triangle has a condition for their edges $a$, $b$, $c$,  so all edge length  must satify

$$|a-b|<c<a+b$$
or 
$$|a-c|<b<a+c$$
or
$$|b-c|<a<b+c$$

Is there any such limitations for a tetrahedron?

It is obvious that  upper limit is

$$S_1<S_2+S_3+S_4$$

$$S_2<S_1+S_3+S_4$$

$$S_3<S_1+S_2+S_4$$

$$S_4<S_1+S_2+S_3$$

What is the lower limit condition for a tetrahedron as we have for a triangle $|a-b|<c$? How can the lower limit condition of a surface on a tetrahedron  be defined by other surfaces such as $f(S_2,S_3,S_4)<S_1<S_2+S_3+S_4$

Thanks for answers

Comment: related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477964/inequality-for-each-a-b-c-d-being-each-area-of-four-faces-of-a-tetrahedron

Comment: And achille hui showed there that given 4 positive numbers $S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4$, in order for them to be realizable as the four face areas of a non-degenerate tetrahedron, a necessary and sufficient condition is the four inequalities you write.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, the reverse triangle inequality follows from
$$
b < a + c,\qquad
c < a + b
$$
by rearranging to $b - c < a$ and $c - b < a$, i.e., $|b - c| < a$.

Analogously, the three necessary conditions
\begin{align*}
%S_{1} < S_{2} + S_{3} + S_{4}, \\
S_{2} &< S_{1} + S_{3} + S_{4}, \\
S_{3} &< S_{1} + S_{2} + S_{4}, \\
S_{4} &< S_{1} + S_{2} + S_{3}
\end{align*}
are equivalent to
\begin{align*}
%S_{1} < S_{2} + S_{3} + S_{4}, \\
S_{2} - (S_{3} + S_{4}) &< S_{1}, \\
S_{3} - (S_{2} + S_{4}) &< S_{1}, \\
S_{4} - (S_{2} + S_{3}) &< S_{1}.
\end{align*}
Combining the first two,
\begin{align*}
|S_{2} - S_{3}| - S_{4} &< S_{1}, \\
S_{4} - (S_{2} + S_{3}) &< S_{1}.
\end{align*}
There are six other necessary inequalities obtained by cyclic permutation of all four indices.

[Is the volume of a tetrahedron determined by the surface areas of the faces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477964) linked by mathlove in the comments addresses sufficient conditions.

Comment: Can we have only one lower condition ? or impossible. If it exists, it should be cyclic .for example,  the lower condition could be $|S_2-S_3|+|S_3-S_4|+|S_2-S_4|<S_1$   but I do not know if it exists  such cyclic condition or how to prove that it is impossible to eliminate 3 necessary condition into one condition.

Comment: There's the maximum of the lower bounds, which is easily shown to be symmetric in $S_{2}$, $S_{3}$, $S_{4}$, but that seems unlikely to be aesthetically satisfactory....